# Embedding facebook videos in website

Tags: facebook-graph-api

Using the Graph API I request `/me?fields=videos.type(uploaded).fields(id, embed_html)`. This gives me a list of my uploaded videos:

```
{
  "id": "[...snip...]", 
  "videos": {
    "data": [
      {
        "id": "10151488520332264", 
        "embed_html": "<iframe src=\"https://graph.facebook.com/video/embed?video_id=10151488520332264\" width=\"190\" height=\"240\" frameborder=\"0\"></iframe>", 
        "updated_time": "2013-02-28T11:09:14+0000"
      },
      [...snip...]
    ]
  }
}
```

I expect `embed_html` to be html code that embeds the video. But when I use it, the iframe shows only a graph error:

```
{
   "error": {
      "message": "Unknown path components: /embed",
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "code": 2500
   }
}
```

The video is public and I get the same error also in the graph explorer when requesting it with an access token that has permissions for `user_videos`.

The `video` object also has a `source` property which links directly to the source video file (no player). I could use that and build my own player, but I'd prefer to use the embed code that facebook thinks is best for the video (and browser).

Comment: This is most definitely a bug. I've filed [a bug report](This is most definitely a bug) you are most welcome to subscribe and confirm that it is reproducible.

Comment: @Lix I guess it's this one: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/531030090271042 .. Subscribed and confirmed

Comment: Actually this one : https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/616979334985053?browse=search_5130b8680cdd75b07320340

Comment: @Lix, obviously they didn't understand your bug report (although it was VERY clear), since they answered to a question you didn't ask. I added the "more information" they asked for.